# Characterization of Extended Lucky Numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The [Lucky Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_number) is a sieve where one starts out with the positive integers:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 ...
```

and then eliminate every 2nd number:

```
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39 41 43 ...
```

Since the next element to "survive" is 3, then eliminate every third element in the list:

```
1 3 7 9 13 15 19 21 25 27 31 33 37 39 43 ...
```

and so on (the next step is removing every 7th element). The final numbers that are not removed are so called the "lucky numbers."

I have an extension of these numbers: when we eliminate every $i$th number, do the same process $i$ times. For example, with our original list:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 ...
```

we remove every 2nd number 2 times:

```
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39 41 43 ... (1st time)
1 5 9 13 17 21 25 29 33 37 41 ... (2nd time)
```

and so on (the next step involves removing every 5th element 5 times).

Is there a characterization to the "surviving" numbers?

Comment: [Here are the first 500 numbers](http://pastebin.com/1f9a4vdW). [Here is a plot of them](http://i.stack.imgur.com/D11Ul.png). [And here is a log plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lUjh1.png). That last run continues until n = 841 (the next number to be sieved out). Note that each of the gaps corresponds to one of the numbers in the sequence. (The last 4 gaps occur at `n` in `{205, 233, 253, 285}`.) And conversely, the long runs correspond to gaps in the sequence.

Comment: @MartinBüttner that's really cool, thanks! Mind sharing the source code you used to generate those?

Comment: Ugh, sorry, didn't save it. I basically used the Mathematica code I posted for the PPCG challenge that inspired this question, and wrapping the body of the `For` loop in a `Do[...,{m}]`. (And then I just fed the result for `ListPlot` and `ListLogPlot`.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner thanks anyway! It is interesting that on the log plot there is always 3 smaller runs followed by a longer one.

Comment: That's because the first few numbers appear in groups of 4, so they create four nearby gaps. The next run is much longer (the numbers from 841 to 3453 - 28 numbers I think) - so the next "staircase" will be much longer than 3 "steps". This means that the gap distribution will follow the same pattern as the numbers themselves.